# Folding Over User Input in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, fold

I'm new to Haskell and have been programming a simple hangman game to get used to the language. I'm storing the game state in a datatype called GameState.

```hs
data GameState = GameState
  { word :: String,
    blanks :: String,
    wrongGuesses :: [Char]
  } deriving Show
```

I also have a function to update the state given an input character and another function to check if the game is finished.

```hs
updateState :: GameState -> Char -> GameState
updateState state c
  | (c `elem` (word state)) = state { blanks = newBlanks }
  | otherwise = state { wrongGuesses = c:(wrongGuesses state)}
  where newBlanks = foldr replaceAt (blanks state) $ elemIndices c (word state)
        replaceAt i = (take i) <> (const [c]) <> (drop (i + 1))

isPlaying :: GameState -> Bool
isPlaying state = ('_' `elem` (blanks state)) && (length (wrongGuesses state) < 5)
```

Given a list of characters, I can do a fold to simulate the game on the given input.

```hs
runGame :: GameState -> [Char] -> [GameState]
runGame initialState chars = takeWhile isPlaying $ scanl updateState initialState chars
```

My question is how to adapt this code to work with actual user input. I've tried using sequence, but the program just endlessly gets user input.

```hs
main = runGame (newState "secret") <$> (sequence $ repeat getChar)
```

Is there any way to fold over getChar similar to how runGame works and print the game state after each user input? I'd like to avoid explicit recursion like runGame does, and if possible, I'd like to stick with standard library functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: why doesn’t your program work? The issue is that when you do `repeat getChar`, that repeats `getChar` *infinitely*. Then you use `sequence`; because of how `sequence` is implemented, it needs to go through the *whole* list before returning. But that list is infinite! Result: an infinite loop.

Now, let’s try to solve this. Often the first thing I do in this sort of scenario is to forget about functions such as `sequence` and just write it as a recursive function:

```hs
main = runGameIO (newState "secret")
  where
    runGameIO :: GameState -> IO ()
    runGameIO curState = do
        input <- getChar
        let newState = updateState curState input
        if isPlaying newState        -- if still playing
            then runGameIO newState  -- then repeat with new state
            else return ()           -- else finish
```

Now, is there any way to simplify `runGameIO`? I can’t see any as it is now. Certainly, we can see now that `sequence` won’t work: `sequence` requires that each item given to it is independent, i.e. each monadic action doesn’t depend on a previous monadic action. (That’s why you can also implement `sequence` with an `Applicative` constraint instead of a `Monad` constraint.) But this problem is all *about* responding given the previous state! So clearly `sequence` won’t work.

Next, let’s desugar the do-notation to see if we can spot anything:

```hs
runGameIO :: GameState -> Io ()
runGameIO curState =
    getChar >>= \input ->
    let newState = updateState curState input
    in if isPlaying newState then runGameIO newState else return ()
```

Hmm… still nothing, really. But this makes it more obvious that you can use `fmap` here:

```hs
runGameIO :: GameState -> Io ()
runGameIO curState =
    fmap (updateState curState) getChar >>= \newState ->
    if isPlaying newState then runGameIO newState else return ()
```

At this point, there’s often some clever trick which can be used to get rid of the explicit recursion. But I can’t see anything to do here. If you weren’t restricting yourself to the standard library, I would say to use [`iterateUntilM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:iterateUntilM) from the `monad-loops` package, but you can’t use that. Sometimes explicit recursion is just best, and this seems to be one of those cases.